# java8 Collector.tomap with merge function to put valus into collector when duplicated keys

Tags: java, collections

Assume having code below, how can return list with duplicated key?

```
private List<Book> getDummyBooks() {
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
        books.add(new Book("The Fellowship of the Ring", 1954, "0395489318"));
        books.add(new Book("The Two Towers", 1954, "0345339711"));
        books.add(new Book("The Return of the King", 1955, "0618129111"));
        return books;
    }
// first object is returned when duplicated key
private Map<Integer, Book> listToMapWithMerge(List<Book> books) {
        return books.stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                        Book::getReleaseYear
                        , Function.identity()
                        , (exising,replacement) -> exising));
    }
```

what if want to return List with duplicated key?

```
private Map<Integer, List<Book> > listToMapWithMerge(List<Book> books) {
        return books.stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                        Book::getReleaseYear
                        , new ArrayList<>Function.identity()
                        , ...));
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Collectors.groupingBy`:

```java
private Map<Integer, List<Book>> listToMapWithMerge(List<Book> books) {
    return books.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Book::getReleaseYear));
}
```